# How to Play MP3 file from certian position in Xamarin.Forms using CrossMediaManager

Tags: xamarin.forms, plugin.media.crossmedia

I am downloading files to the local storage in my `Xamarin Forms` application. I am using [CrossMediaManager](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager) to play those stored local mp3 files. The problem is the player doesn't start playing audio from certain position. It always starts playing form zero.

I am using below code but didn't help. I have also tried to queue media files and play them but didn't help.

```
if (Helper.FileExists(filePath))
   {
      var position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(AyasAudios[AyaNumber].StartingPoint);
      Debug.WriteLine("starting point: " + AyasAudios[AyaNumber].StartingPoint + " position: " + position);
      await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(new FileInfo(filePath));
      await CrossMediaManager.Current.SeekTo(position);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can not invoke `CrossMediaManager.Current.SeekTo` immediately after `CrossMediaManager.Current.Play` in **CrossMediaManager** .

That means we should better invoke `SeekTo` after player is `IsPlaying` status .

**Therefore** can separate them to invoke them as follow :

```
private async void Button_Clicked_Play(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("https://ia800806.us.archive.org/15/items/Mp3Playlist_555/AaronNeville-CrazyLove.mp3");
}

private async void Button_Clicked_SeekTo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CrossMediaManager.Current.IsPlaying())
    {
        await CrossMediaManager.Current.SeekTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    }
}
```